# Matching method name in kotlin/java

Tags: android, kotlin

I was playing around with `ObjectAnimator` and I created a simple drawable.

```
// In my drawable file

fun setMyCustomParameter(...) {
    blah blah blah
}
```

To run the animation I have the following object animator:

```
val orreryAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
            myDrawable,
            "MyCustomParameter",
            drawableEvaluator, // irrelevant
            startValues, // irrelevant 
            endValues // irrelevant
    )
```

Right now `"MyCustomParameter"` is a hardcoded string value that I match with my method `setMyCustomParameter`. The problem is that if I do not want to manually match it because if I accidentally misspell then the code will still run except the animation will have no effect. I want to ask is there a way to get the method `setMycustomParameter` as a string so that I can guarantee that even if I change the method name later on the code just runs without me having to remember changing the string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can: `myDrawable::setMyCustomParameter` will give you a reference to the method, which has a name: `myDrawable::setMyCustomParameter.name`. 
See [Callable References](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references) in the documentation.

Also, if you have `getMyCustomParameter` and `setMyCustomParameter`, you may want to modify it to a property with custom [getter and setter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters):

```
var myCustomParameter: Type
    get() = ...
    set(value: Type) { ... }
```